# Unit testing - getting TypeError: You provided an invalid object where a stream was expected

Tags: angular, jasmine, ngrx, jasmine-marbles

I'm trying to do a unit test where an effect uses a service to fetch results from an API, then fires either a success action, or an error action. I keep getting the error `TypeError: You provided an invalid object where a stream was expected. You can provide an Observable, Promise, Array, or Iterable.`. Not entirely sure what needs to be changed to get this working.

Including the error check test and relevant code.

Angular

```
Angular CLI: 7.1.4
Node: 10.5.0
OS: win32 x64
Angular: 7.1.4
... animations, cli, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... http, language-service, platform-browser
... platform-browser-dynamic, router

Package                           Version
-----------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect         0.10.7
@angular-devkit/build-angular     0.10.7
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer   0.10.7
@angular-devkit/build-webpack     0.10.7
@angular-devkit/core              7.0.7
@angular-devkit/schematics        7.1.4
@angular/cdk                      7.2.0
@angular/material                 7.2.0
@ngtools/webpack                  7.0.7
@schematics/angular               7.1.4
@schematics/update                0.11.4
rxjs                              6.3.3
typescript                        3.1.6
webpack                           4.19.1
```

Test

```
describe('ResultsEffects', () => {
    let store: jasmine.SpyObj<Store<FeatureState>>;
    let ebs: jasmine.SpyObj<EBSService>;
    let snackbar: jasmine.SpyObj<SnackBarService>;

    beforeEach(() => {
        store = jasmine.createSpyObj('store', ['pipe']);
        ebs = jasmine.createSpyObj('EBSService', ['getPollResults', 'getUserHasVoted', 'getSettings']);
        snackbar = jasmine.createSpyObj('SnackBarService', ['notify']);
    });

    describe('fetchResults', () => {
        it(`should dispatch 'FetchPanelResultsError'`, () => {
            const fetchAction = new FetchPanelResults();
            const error = { statusText: 'ERROR' };
            const errorAction = new FetchPanelResultsError({ error: error.statusText });
            const values = {
                a: fetchAction,
                e: errorAction
            };
            const source = cold('a', values);
            const expected = cold('--e', values);
            const actions = new Actions(source);

            ebs.getPollResults.and.returnValue(throwError(error));

            const effects = new ResultsEffects(
                actions,
                store,
                snackbar,
                ebs
            );

            expect(
                effects.fetchResults$({
                    debounce: 20,
                    scheduler: getTestScheduler()
                })
            ).toBeObservable(expected);
        });
    });
});
```

Effect

```
@Effect()
fetchResults$ = ({ debounce = 500, scheduler = asyncScheduler } = {}) => this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType<SetPanelResults>(PanelResultsActionTypes.FETCH_PANEL_RESULTS),
    // need alternate method for this
    // withLatestFrom(this.featureState$),
    // map(([_, state]) => state.twitch.token),
    debounceTime(debounce, scheduler),
    switchMap((token) =>
        this.ebs.getPollResults(token).pipe(
            map(res => new SetPanelResults(res.data.results)),
            catchError(error => of(new FetchPanelResultsError({ error: error.statusText })))
        )
    )
)
```

Service

```
getPollResults(token: string): Observable<PollResultsFetchData> {
    const options = {
        headers: ebsHeaders(token)
    };

    return this.http.get<PollResultsFetchData>(`${this.ebsURL}/poll/results`, options);
}
```

Update: Added debounce to trigger the error with marbles. Still need alternative to `withLatestFrom`.

Comment: Wrap `expected` with of() in the test. `expect(effects.fetchResults$()).toBeObservable(of(expected));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comments:

The problem is that `withLatest` from isn't really returning anything because you don't have a feature state. This is because you mock out the store with `jasmine.createSpyObj('store', ['pipe'])`.

To solve this use the "real" ngrx store or use the [mock store](https://github.com/ngrx/platform/pull/1027), which was implemented in NgRx 7.

Comment: When I try that I get the same error. I'm following the pattern used [here](https://github.com/tomastrajan/angular-ngrx-material-starter/blob/master/src/app/examples/stock-market/stock-market.effects.spec.ts#L79). I've cloned that repo, and run the tests and they all pass.

Comment: I think we're on the right track. I added a debounce as my error wasn't triggering, and then removing the withLatestFrom fixed the error. Now I just need to figure out the alternative method for getting something off the state without losing my action and not breaking the Observable.

Comment: Yep, changing it to a mock store instead of a spy has now resolved the issue. Thanks so much for the help!

Answer (score 0):

For me that error started to happen regularly for a couple of months (Angular 7) on Live Reload during development. I was fixing it just by re-opening browser with a few seconds pause.

Today re-opening didn't help and I occasionally figured out, that re-saving one of source file (even without actually changing it) helps out and error dissapears. Re-saving triggers project in-memory build recompilation by webpack and live reload